# Optimize / Speed Up AngularJS HTML rendering - Performance Issue

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, performance

This is probably not the first question on this topic, but since it took me hours finding out I couldn't find a good solution, I still want to ask you guys here.

I would like to **optimize** following code, because the page needs a **few seconds to load** right now. If I take that part out of the page (it is only one part of it), the page loads in max 1 second.

FYI: I only have **4 routes** for the student that I test my application with.

```
<tr ng-repeat="route in student.itin">
      <td>
         <select ng-options="airline._id as airline.code for airline in ::airlines | orderBy: 'code'" ng-model="route.airline" class="form-control"/>
      </td>
      <td>
         <input type="text" ng-model="route.flight_number" maxlength="4" size="4" class="form-control"/>
      </td>
      <td>
         <input type="text" ng-model="route.class" maxlength="1" size="1" class="form-control"/>
      </td>
      <td>
         <select ng-options="airport._id as airport.code for airport in ::airports | orderBy: 'code'" ng-model="route.departure.airport" class="form-control"/>
      </td>
      <td>
         <div class="form-group has-feedback" ng-class="{'has-error': route.arrival.date < route.departure.date}">
             <input type="text" class="form-control" is-open="datepickers['departure_date' + $index]" max-date="route.arrival.date" timepicker-options="timepicker_options" ng-focus="open($event, 'departure_date'+$index)" datetime-picker="{{ ::datetimepicker_format }}" ng-model="route.departure.date" />

             <span ng-if="route.arrival.date < route.departure.date" tooltip-placement="right" tooltip="Arrival Date cannot be before Departure Date" tooltip-trigger="mouseenter" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove form-control-feedback" aria-hidden="true"></span>
         </div>
      </td>
      <td>
         <select ng-options="airport._id as airport.code for airport in ::airports | orderBy: 'code'" ng-model="route.arrival.airport" class="form-control"/>
      </td>
      <td>
         <div class="form-group has-feedback" ng-class="{'has-error': route.arrival.date < route.departure.date}">
             <input type="text" class="form-control" is-open="datepickers['arrival_date' + $index]" min-date="route.departure.date" timepicker-options="timepicker_options" ng-focus="open($event, 'arrival_date'+$index)" datetime-picker="{{ ::datetimepicker_format }}" ng-model="route.arrival.date" />

             <span ng-if="route.arrival.date < route.departure.date" tooltip-placement="right" tooltip="Arrival Date cannot be before Departure Date" tooltip-trigger="mouseenter" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove form-control-feedback" aria-hidden="true"></span>
         </div>
      </td>
      <td>
         <input type="text" ng-model="route.filekey" class="form-control"/>
      </td>
      <td class="text-right">
         <a class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="deleteRoute($index)" tooltip-placement="top" tooltip="Delete route" tooltip-trigger="mouseenter">
              <i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i>
         </a>
      </td>
</tr>
```

What I have learned from my research is pretty much that I shouldn't use too much **ng-repeat**, try to **minimize data-binding** and **filters**. But after applying everything I have learned, I came up with the code above and don't know how to go on optimizing, since this is not enough.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

- add `track by` to your ng-repeat
- remove filters where it is possible
- use one time binding with `::`

Or switch to ReactJS.

Answer (score 1):

Try to improve `ng-repeat` if your AngularJS is above 1.4.1: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat#tracking-and-duplicates

Comment: Thank you. The code above is AngularJS 1.3.15. What tracking functionality do you recommend exactly?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use sly-repeat directive instead ng-repeat: http://blog.scalyr.com/2013/10/angularjs-1200ms-to-35ms/

Comment: Sly-Repeat does not work for Angular 1.3.x currently. But still thank you!